# Как замедлить ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, процесс, процессор

Конвертирую видео командой

```
ffmpeg -i "file.mp4" -vcodec h264 -acodec copy -tune film "..\Converted\file.mp4"
```

при этом процессор нагревается до 78-81 градуса - вроде приемлемо. Но при нагреве до 80 нажинает противно пищать вентилятор, что очень раздражает.

Поэтому вопрос: можно ли как-то уменьшить скорость конвертирования с целью снижения нагрузки на процессор и уменьшения его температуры?

Кстати, делается последовательная обработка всех файлов в папке, т. е. на каждый обрабатываемый файл запускается новый процесс ffmpeg.

PS: Уменьшение приоритета процесса не помогает.

Comment: Попробуйте задать меньше потоков, что бы не загружался весь процессор `-threads <count>`

Comment: Ещё как вариант, задать исполнение процесса только для определенных ядер: параметр **affinity** для команды **start**, запускающей определенное приложение.